# How to make text alignment of Visio shapes using Python(Win32 module)

Tags: python, vba, win32com, visio, text-alignment

I read the documentation of VBA and couldn't convert this to Python code.
I simply created shape and tried to make its align right.
If I delete alignment line of code, rest code works perfectly.
I don't know, I might be using wrong VBA objects and methods. I'm open to your advices. If you provide me your solution code, I would be very appreciated.

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
app.Visible = True
my_shape = page.DrawRectangle(3, 3, 5, 5)) # Draw rectangle
my_shape.Text = "Hello world!" # Add text to rectangle 
my_shape.LineStyle = "None" # Add some styling
my_shape.Characters.ParaProps['visHorzAlign'] = 'visAlignRight' #Tried alignment here
my_shape.SetCenter(4.4281, 3) # Change position of rectangle
```

Here is the error
[image]

Related documentations and forums that I found:

1. http://www.44342.com/visio-f963-t1206-p1.htm
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

app = win32.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
app.Visible = True
page = app.Documents.AddEx("", 1, 0).Pages(1)  # create new document and get 1 page
my_shape = page.DrawRectangle(3, 3, 5, 5)  # Draw rectangle
my_shape.Text = "Hello world!"  # Add text to rectangle
my_shape.LineStyle = "None"  # Add some styling
my_shape.Cells("Para.HorzAlign").FormulaU = "2"  # 2 - right alignment
# or use my_shape.CellsSRC(4, 0, 6).FormulaU = "2" #visSectionParagraph=4, visHorzAlign=6
my_shape.SetCenter(4.4281, 3)  # Change position of rectangle
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thanks a lot. 
Could you please help me what steps did you do to find a solution :) I'm also searching docs but couldn't find smt like "Para.HorzAlign"

Comment: It's simple. Launched the Visio macro recorder, did the text alignment. Received a code like `Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID (1) .CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign) .FormulaU =" 2 "`. Then using `Debug.Print ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC (visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).Name` got `Para.HorzAlign`. Essentially, the macro recorder is a handy help system.

Comment: I got the idea. I did the same steps as you recommended, and got the result, thank you very much. For my future projects, in addition to Python, I will try to learn some VBA :)